# IIS Simple redirect rule does not work

Tags: rewrite, 301-redirect, iis-10

I'm changing forum software for my website. I would like to redirect the board URLs.
For example, The old URLs are example.com/forum/genika/board1 and the new URLs are example.com/forum/boards/board1

I've created this simple rule:

```
<rule name="forum/genika" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="*/forum/genika/*" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/forum/boards/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Testing the pattern of the whole url https://www.example.com/forum/genika/board1 matches the wildcard pattern, and I'm using {R:1} and {R:2} accordingly.

This doesn't make sense. It must be an IIS glitch or something else?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rule name="forum/genika" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="forum/genika/*" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="forum/boards/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Reference

https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59